# Create React Dynamic Forms

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6

I am trying to achieve a dynamic form using react hooks and .map();

What I have achieved so far is to generate the form static like in this example :
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ndh9q

this is my static form :

```
<form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <Grid container spacing={4}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <TextField id="profile" label="Name" fullWidth={true} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <TextField id="profile" label="Email" fullWidth={true} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <TextField id="profile" label="Address" fullWidth={true} />
        </Grid>
        {/* textarea */}
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <TextField
            label="Info"
            multiline
            rows={1}
            rowsMax={4}
            fullWidth={true}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
```

and here I am trying to make the form dynamic:

```
const initialState = { name: "", email: "", address: "", info: "" };

export default function BasicTextFields() {

const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({ ...initialState });

return(
<form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <Grid container spacing={4}>
      {inputs.map((item, index) => (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <TextField id={index`${item}`} label={item} fullWidth={true} />
        </Grid>
      )}
  </Grid>
    </form>
)}
```

but it is returning error, not sure why, can someone help me also with a detailed info please.
keep in mind that also **last field of the form is a textarea** so gets particular attribute.

ThankYou !

Comment: If i'm not wrong, your `inputs` is an object, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found there is some issue in your code.

1. Since your `inputs` is an Object you can't directly use map on it. I've used `Object.keys()` to use `map`.
2. Also there was some issue in your `template` literals.

Here is your `form` element with dynamic content.

```
<form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
  <Grid container spacing={4}>
    {
      Object.keys(inputs).map((key, index) => {
        if(key === 'info') {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
            <TextField
              label={key}
              multiline
              rows={1}
              rowsMax={4}
              fullWidth={true}
            />
            </Grid>
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <TextField id={`index${key}`} label={key} fullWidth={true} />
        </Grid>
          )
        }
    })
  }
  </Grid>
</form>
```

Here is the [codesandbox_link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-0282c?file=/demo.js).

Comment: and If I have multiple types of fields I guess the if condition for each, right ? Thank you :)

Comment: Yes. Welcome :)